# HTML5 canvas zoom my drawings

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hello i create program like a paint on HTML5 canvas. I have problem i need create few tools drawing and zoom. I don't have idea how to create zoom without delay. Drawing example: http://jsfiddle.net/x5rrvcr0/

How i can zooming my drawings?

drawing code:

```
    <style>
        canvas {
            background-color: #CECECE;
        }

        html, body {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
        }
    </style>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var paintCanvas = document.getElementById("paintCanvas");
        var paintCtx = paintCanvas.getContext("2d");

        var size = 500;

        paintCanvas.width = size;
        paintCanvas.height = size;

        var draw = false;
        var prevMouseX = 0;
        var prevMouseY = 0;

        function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {

            evt = evt.originalEvent || window.event || evt;
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();


            if (evt.clientX !== undefined && evt.clientY !== undefined) {
                return {
                    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
                    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
                };   
            }
        } 





        $("#paintCanvas").on("mousedown", function(e) {
            draw = true;
            var coords = getMousePos(paintCanvas);
            prevMouseX = coords.x;
            prevMouseY = coords.y;
        });

        $("#paintCanvas").on("mousemove", function(e) {
            if(draw) {
                var coords = getMousePos(paintCanvas, e);

                paintCtx.beginPath();
                paintCtx.lineWidth = 10;
                paintCtx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
                paintCtx.moveTo(prevMouseX, prevMouseY);
                paintCtx.lineTo(coords.x, coords.y);
                paintCtx.stroke();

                prevMouseX = coords.x;
                prevMouseY = coords.y;
            }
        });

        $("#paintCanvas").on("mouseup", function(e) {
            draw = false;
        });


    });
</script>



<body>
    <canvas id="paintCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is the zoom code you have problems with? Please post that as well so we can have a look at it.

Comment: i don't have zoom code, i need idea how to make it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the pixelated effect in the zoom, you need to draw on a temp canvas, then only after copy that temp canvas to the main screen.
You no longer need to zoom in the temp canvas, just draw on 1:1 scale always. When copying to the view canvas, then you apply the zoom (and maybe translate) that you want.

Keep in mind that drawings are anti-aliased, so you when zooming you will see some shades of grey when drawing in black, for instance.

I kept the recording code of @FurqanZafar since it is a good idea to record things in case you want to perform undo : in that case just delete the last record entry and redraw everything.

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/x5rrvcr0/4/

```
function updatePaintCanvas() {
    paintContext.clearRect(0, 0, paintContext.canvas.width, paintContext.canvas.height);
    paintContext.save();
    paintContext.translate(cvSize * 0.5, cvSize * 0.5);
    paintContext.scale(scale, scale);
    paintContext.drawImage(drawCanvas, -cvSize * 0.5, -cvSize * 0.5);
    paintContext.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Heres the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x5rrvcr0/2/ with basic zooming functionality

If you draw multiple paths on mouse move then your sketch will appear broken or disconnected, instead you should only stroke a single path until "mouseup" event.

You can then store these paths in an array and later redraw them at different zoom levels:

```
    function zoom(context, paths, styles, scale) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
        context.save();
        applyStyles(context, styles);
        scaleFromCenter(context, scale);
        for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
            context.beginPath();                
            context.moveTo(paths[i][0].x, paths[i][0].y);                
            for (var j = 1; j < paths[i].length; j++)
                context.lineTo(paths[i][j].x, paths[i][j].y);
            context.stroke();
        }
        context.restore();
    };
```

Comment: redrawing is not good solve, because if paint have unique brushes, like a variable by mouse speed, preasure and etc this method cannot redrawing correctly

Comment: @Yourchoice : redrawing is the way to go, it will re-draw exactly what was recorded. It won't handle handle pressure, sure, but the mouse doesn't either, so fine :-)

Comment: this method like a svg, if you zoom you cannot see pixel by pixel on this method.. I need realistic zoom if zoomed i can see pixel

Comment: as @GameAlchemist mentioned, redrawing is the weapon of choice. If you want sharp edges, you need to create new Pixels and that is done by redrawing. To speed up this process you could implement it in an way that only the visible parts are actually redrawn…